# R Calculate distance between two points in British National Grid

Tags: r, distance, r-sf

I would like to calculate the distance between two sets of British National Grid coordinates in each row in a dataset (i.e. the distance between AreaA and AreaB for each row in my example) in kilometres.

```
library("sf")                 
                                  
BBox <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -10000, xmax = 15000, ymax = 20000, ymin = -5000), crs = st_crs(27700)) %>% st_as_sfc()                              
P1 <- st_sample(BBox, 50, exact = TRUE)                               
P2 <- st_sample(BBox, 50, exact = TRUE)                                   
                                        
Points <- data.frame(AreaA=sample(110:190,50,replace=FALSE),AreaB=sample(10:90,50,replace=FALSE))                           
Points$AreaA_X <- data.frame(st_coordinates(P1))[,1]
Points$AreaA_Y <- data.frame(st_coordinates(P1))[,2]                              
Points$AreaB_X <- data.frame(st_coordinates(P2))[,1]
Points$AreaB_Y <- data.frame(st_coordinates(P2))[,2]
```

Comment: You can do this in many ways. For sf object classes `sf::st_distance` works and for sp classes `sp::spDists` or `rgeos:gDistance`. These functions return distance matrices. If you are wanting a knn approach for returning k neighbors (eg., first 2 nearest neighbors) you can use the `spatialEco::knn` function which can use geographic distance (coordinates) or can be based on a multivariate distance (using a design matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the answer while asking my question. However, I thought I would still post the question and my answer in case it helps anyone else in the future.

```
Points_sf <- st_as_sf(Points, coords = c("AreaA_X","AreaA_Y"),crs=27700)            
Points_sf$geometry2 <- st_as_sf(Points[,c("AreaB_X","AreaB_Y")], coords = c("AreaB_X","AreaB_Y"),crs=27700) 
Points_sf$Distance_M <- st_distance(Points_sf$geometry, Points_sf$geometry2, by_element = TRUE)
```